# How can I update a variable after render?

Tags: react-native

Hi this is my code in App.js

```
var music = {
  name: "Starboy",
  artist: "The Weeknd",
  albumArt: "",
  length: "4:20",
  audioURL:"",

};

export default class App extends Component 
{
  render() {
  return (
    <Image style={styles.albumArt} source={{ uri:music.albumArt }} />
  );
  }
};
```

I have another function in lastFM.js

```
export function getAlbumArt(albumName) 
{
    fetch('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album='+albumName+'&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json&limit=1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
        const image = result.results.albummatches.album[0].image[2]['#text'];
        console.log(image);
        return image;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: "+error);
    });
}
```

How can I update **music.albumArt** in **App.js** and re-render **Image** inside **App.js Render**?

Comment: you might want to look into `react life cycle methods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. Re-render happens when you change the state of the component. So, here we are updating the state once we get data from the API.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "Starboy",
      artist: "The Weeknd",
      albumArt: "",
      length: "4:20",
      audioURL: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album='+albumName+'&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json&limit=1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
        const image = result.results.albummatches.album[0].image[2]['#text'];
        console.log(image);
        this.setState({...this.state, albumArt: image });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: "+error);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <Image style={styles.albumArt} source={{ uri: this.state.albumArt }} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I looking for. I have one extra question, whenever I setState in any function inside App class, re-render happens? Or this is happens only in "componentDidMount" ?